# If condition inside nested for loop in android

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two `ArrayList`s of the same model class (i.e `ListA` and `ListB`) to which I have added the same data.
Then I added some data only in the second arraylist `ListB`.

Now, I want to fetch only that data which is different in both `ListA` and `ListB` and store the result in a third arraylist `ListC`.

I tried below code. However, *all* elements are stored in `ListC`, as opposed to only those that are different:

```
ArrayList<C> ListC = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < ListA.size(); i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < ListB.size(); j++) {

        if (ListA.get(i).getName() == ListB.get(j).getName()) {

            Log.e("Do", "Nothing");

        } else {
            C c = new C(b.get(j).getName());
            ListC.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

> Edited Question

```
ArrayList<Model> a = new ArrayList<>();
Model model = new Model();
model.setName("MaHi");
model.setAge("20");
a.add(model);

ArrayList<Model> b = new ArrayList<>();
Model model = new Model();
model.setName("MaHi");
model.setAge("20");
b.add(model);
Model model2 = new Model();
model2.setName("Ritu");
model2.setAge("21");
b.add(model2);

ArrayList<Model> c=new ArrayList<>();
```

now I want to fetch that data which is not in either arraylist a or arraylist b (i.e. data of model2) into arraylist of c;

Comment: What result *do* you get, and what did you *expect*? lease read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*. Also, your problem is not related to android, you should remove that tag.

Comment: I just want that name which is not same in both ArrayList -A,B. But I got all the names

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Please modify question to include description of why the code is wrong.

Comment: i think he has explained his requirement very clearly

Comment: I think the problem is, given that the names are strings, that you use the == operator. Try ListA.get(i).getName().equals( ListB.get(j).getName() )

Comment: @Mahesh, **Shrenik Shah** answer is correct, because in java `String` is a referenced type and `==` checks for the same object not the same character sequence.

Comment: I have edited my question. please see

Comment: @Mahesh you are not so clear and also not so aware with stackoverflow. changing question even a word can change lot of things. from next time be clear with your requirements

Comment: I again edited my question, please review and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have different class model(A,B) for all list, `contains` and `remove` methods might not be helpful for you, so you can use a flag `contained` like this:

```
Arraylist<C> ListC = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < ListB.size(); i++) {
    // initially, assume that this element is not contained in ListA
    boolean contained = false;

    // check if this element is contained in ListA
    for (int j = 0; j < ListA.size(); j++) {
        if (ListA.get(i).getName().equals(ListB.get(j).getName())) {
            contained = true;
        }
    }

    // if this element is not contained once in ListA,
    if (!contained) {
        // add it to ListC
        C c = new C();
        c.setName(b.get(j).getName());
        ListC.add(c);
    }
}
```

This flag indicates, for every element in `ListB`, if it is contained at least once in `ListA`.
This ensures that each element in `ListB` is added *at most* once—your loop could add each element multiple times.

Comment: I felt free to add some explanations how the code works. An illustration *why* the original codes does not work is in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39589910/1314743).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are iterating over all *combinations*.

Lets say `A = [1, 2, 3]` and `B = [1, 3, 4]`.
Then, your loop would compare

- `a=1` with `b=1`. Both are equal, nothing is done. That's good.
- `a=1` with `b=3`. They are not equal, so 3 is added to `C`. Here is your first problem: 3 actually is in `A`, but just not in your current iteration.
- `a=1` with `b=4`. They are not equal, so 4 is added to `C`. In this case, this is okay, since 4 is not in `A`.
- `a=2` with `b=1`. They are not equal, so 1 is added to `C`. However, 1 is actually in `A`.
- and so on

Do you see how your solution does not work? You cannot compare every *combination*. Instead, you have to check for every element in `B`, if it is in `A`. If no, add.
This, directly translated to pseudo code, looks like

```
// for every element in ListB
for (int i = 0; i < ListB.length(); i++) {
    B b = ListB.get(i);
    // if this is not in ListA
    if (!ListA.contains(b))
        ListC.add(b);
}
```

However, here you should use the for-each loop `for (B b: ListB)`.
And even better, simply use `ListC.addAll(ListB); ListB.removeAll(ListA)`.
(And make sure `hashCode` and `equals` are properly written - but that is a different issue.)

Of course, this requires that the Elements in `ListA` and `ListB` are of the same type. See [Jekin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39589820/1314743) for a solution using less standard library methods that also works with different types (as long as both implement `getName()`, of course).

This also resolves a second issue, as stated in the comments on your question: You cannot compare Strings with `==`, but have to use the `equals` method. Try `x = new String("a"); y = new String("a"); assert(x==y);` and `assert(x.equals(y));`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here in your code

```
if (ListA.get(i).getName() == ListB.get(j).getName()) {

    Log.e("Do", "Nothing");

} else {
    C c = new C();
    c.setName(b.get(j).getName());
    ListC.add(c);
}
```

You are using `==` operator to compare String values. Which is used for reference comparison not value comparison. While this may produce accurate results in many different programming languages but Java handles value comparisons differently. You need to use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase` method instead of `==`.

So change the line to

```
if (ListA.get(i).getName().equals(ListB.get(j).getName()))
```

**Note :**  An `==` operator can *sometimes* produce correct results but only because the different `String`s' references share the same object not because they have the same value.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
Arraylist<C> ListC = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < ListA.size(); i++) {

     for (int j = 0; j < ListB.size(); j++) {

        if (ListA.get(i).getName().equals(ListB.get(j).getName())) {

            Log.e("Do", "Nothing");

         } else {
            C c = new C();
            c.setName(b.get(j).getName());
            ListC.add(c);
    }
}
}
```

Just let me know if it doesn't resolve your need

i will definitely help you

Comment: you just changed '==' to 'equals'.

Comment: so what ? you were wrong there that is why i did that. it doesn't mean down vote at all. ridiculous

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<>();
    a.add("hello");
    a.add("hi");
    a.add("stack");
    a.add("overflow");
    a.add("empty");
    a.add("world1");
    ArrayList<String> b=new ArrayList<>();
    b.add("hello");
    b.add("hi");
    b.add("stack");
    b.add("overflow");
    b.add("empty");
    b.add("world");
    ArrayList<String> c=new ArrayList<>();
    int flag=0;
    System.out.println(a.contains("empty"));
     for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

        if(b.contains(a.get(i)))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("haii");
            c.add(a.get(i));
        }

    }
    System.out.println(c.toString());
}
```

you try this example